# Adding a framelayout inside a ViewGroup

Tags: android, viewgroup

I have a `LinearLayout` with id of `contentContainer`.
My question is simple:
How do I programmatically create a `Framelayout` and add it at the bottom of my `LinearLayout`?
Then I wanna reference this `FrameLayout` to add a fragment inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams frameParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;

params.addView(frameParams);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to do:

```
final LinearLayout parentView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.contentContainer);
final FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(getContext());
parentView.addView(frameLayout, parentView.getChildCount() - 1);
```

Couldn't test it though right now...